# How to set a 'p' column's width to be the remaining width of a table?

Tags: tables, lyx

I am trying to create a two-column table where the second column fills all remaining width of the table up until \columnwidth.  Here is an simplified example of where I am trying to start from:

```
\noindent \rowcolors[]{1}{}{gray!20}%
\begin{tabular*}{1\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cl}
column 1 header & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2 header}\tabularnewline
autosized column & This column should contain justified text, wrapping at the width of
the table instead of going past it\tabularnewline
some additional rows... & some additional justified text\global\rownum=0\relax\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{2}{p{1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Justified footnotes

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ornare
sapien vel tellus rhoncus, placerat rutrum ipsum pretium. 

Maecenas vel convallis erat. Morbi facilisis, nunc molestie consequat
consectetur, velit turpis facilisis dolor, non tempor mauris nunc
vitae risus. Nullam ante mauris, volutpat ut molestie eget, congue
non velit. Nullam id maximus ligula. }\tabularnewline
\end{tabular*}
```

When this is rendered, the second row of the table extends past the right side of the table. What I would ideally like to do is set right hand column that is currently of type 'l' to be of type 'p', but then I need to explicitly give it a width, and I do not know what this width is.  In the case of the footnotes cell at the bottom, it's easy, because I know it spans the whole table, which I already know is \columnwidth, so I just subtract the tabcolsep margins that the other rows all have in the middle, and it's exactly the right width.

Ultimately, I don't know the width of the first column, because it might contain many more rows and I don't know which row is necessarily the widest entry.

How can I keep the text in the second row from overflowing the right hand side of the table, and wrapping correctly, as a 'p' column would?

Comment: this is exactly what `tabularx` is designed to do, but I would say 99% of the time you have a two column tabularx table it is better to use a list than a table.

Comment: Alas, I'm using LyX, and the version I am using doesn't have tabularx support yet.  :(   Could you elaborate or provide a link to what you referred to for making a two-column list?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to measure the width of the first column using a savebox.  This means inputting the first column twice.

I set the tabular to extend all the way across the column.  Note that the colors extend even further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\newlength{\mywidth}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{c}% measure first column + 2\tabcolsep
column 1 header \\
autosized column \\
some additional rows... 
\end{tabular}}%
\setlength{\mywidth}{\dimexpr \columnwidth - \wd0}% do once

\noindent \rowcolors[]{1}{}{gray!20}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{\mywidth}@{}}
column 1 header & \multicolumn{1}{c}{column 2 header}\\
autosized column & This column should contain justified text, wrapping at the width of
the table instead of going past it\\
some additional rows... & some additional justified text\global\rownum=0\relax\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}{Justified footnotes

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ornare
sapien vel tellus rhoncus, placerat rutrum ipsum pretium. 

Maecenas vel convallis erat. Morbi facilisis, nunc molestie consequat
consectetur, velit turpis facilisis dolor, non tempor mauris nunc
vitae risus. Nullam ante mauris, volutpat ut molestie eget, congue
non velit. Nullam id maximus ligula. }\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]